# How catch Errors with try catch of lower order functions

Tags: javascript, try-catch, throw

I'm trying to catch errors from a function that causes another function that can return an error. Example:

```
async function method1 () {
  throw new Error('method1 error')
  return 'result'
}

async function method2 () {
  const result = await method1()
  return result
}

async function method3 () {
  try {
    const result = await method2()
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
}
method3()
```

How i can catch errors from method1 in method3?

Answer (score 0):

```js
async function method1() {
  try {
    // do whatever you have to
    throw new Error('method1 error'); // <= to be deleted
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error('method1 error'); // generate the custom error
  }
}

async function method2() {
  try {
    const result = await method1();
    return result
  } catch (error) {
    throw error; // "forward" any error
  }

}

async function method3() {
  try {
    const result = await method2();
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
  }
}

method3();
```